# Calculate how many categories I can construct

Tags: python-3.x, hash-map

I would appreciate to have your opinion on this code and whether I can refactor it and make it cleaner.  I don't like the fact that I have 3 nested `for` loops, which makes the complexity of this code O(n³).

```
    categories = {}
    for k1, v1 in res["relationship_types"].items():
        for k2, v2 in res["remote_types"].items():
            count = 0
            for k3, v3 in RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES.items():
                relationship_types = v3["relationship_types"]
                if k1 in relationship_types:
                    target_types = v3["target_types"]
                    if len(target_types) == 0:
                        count = v1
                        categories[k3] = count
                        break
                    elif k2 in target_types:
                        count = min(v1, v2)

                    if k3 in categories:
                        categories[k3] += count
                    else:
                        categories[k3] = count
```

This is my `res`:

```
res={'remote_types': {'identity': 2, 'location': 1, 'indicator': 2}, 'relationship_types': {'targets': 2, 'uses': 1, 'indicates': 2}}
```

And this is my `RELATIONSHIP_CATEGORIES`:

```
RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES = {
    "campaigns": {
        "relationship_types": ["targets"],
        "target_types": ["identity"],
    },
    "ttps": {
        "relationship_types": ["uses"],
        "target_types": ["attack-pattern"],
    }
}
```

What I want to do is calculate how many categories I can construct based on my `res` dictionary.

For instance, for the category `campaigns` of `RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES` I need to have at least one `targets` in my `res["relationship_types"]` and one `identity` in my `res["remote_types"]`, but since I have 2 of each, my `categories` dictionary would look like:

```
categories = {
    "campaigns": 2,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: The actual dictionary produced does not look like your example and also includes `'ttps': 0`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is pretty convoluted, not helped by your mystery `k1`, `k2` (etc.) names. So far as I can tell, you shouldn't be doing any length comparison. Use more meaningful variable names, replace your confusing `target_types` mapping with direct reference to `remote_types`, and you have

```py
res = {
    'remote_types': {'identity': 2, 'location': 1, 'indicator': 2},
    'relationship_types': {'targets': 2, 'uses': 1, 'indicates': 2},
}

RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES = {
    'campaigns': {
        'relationship_types': ['targets'],
        'remote_types': ['identity'],
    },
    'ttps': {
        'relationship_types': ['uses'],
        'remote_types': ['attack-pattern'],
    },
}

categories = {
    rel_key: min(
        res_items.get(criterion, 0)
        for res_items, criteria in (
            (res.get(criterion_key, {}), criteria)
            for criterion_key, criteria in rel_criteria.items()
        )
        for criterion in criteria
    )
    for rel_key, rel_criteria in RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES.items()
}
print(categories)
```

or perhaps more legibly

```py
def count_criteria(rel_criteria: dict[str, list[str]]) -> Iterator[int]:
    for criterion_key, criteria in rel_criteria.items():
        res_items = res.get(criterion_key, {})
        for criterion in criteria:
            yield res_items.get(criterion, 0)

categories = {
    rel_key: min(count_criteria(rel_criteria))
    for rel_key, rel_criteria in RELATIONSHIPS_CATEGORIES.items()
}
```

both resulting in

```
{'campaigns': 2, 'ttps': 0}
```

It's not the fastest thing in the world, but strictly speaking this is not true:

> the complexity of this code [is] O(n³)

because your iterations are iterating over dimensions of potentially different sizes. You have not given any hints as to the scale of your problem, so all optimisation may be premature, but if you really needed to run complexity analysis you'd find O(mnp) with `m`, `n` and `p` each a separate dimension. If enough of those dimensions stay constant and low you can effectively consider them to be 1.